# How do get the code to respond if user dose not type anything and just presses enter?

Tags: java

I want my code to respond if the user only presses enter and doesn't type anything else. I use .trim to react to only putting in spaces but, it gives me an error when I just hit enter as the input. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    static Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("What is your first name?");
        String a = name.nextLine();
        String b = a.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + a.substring(1);
        String c = a.trim();
        if (c.length() != 0) {
            if (a.contains(" ")) {
                System.out.println("You put space in your name. : (");
            } else {
                System.out.println(b + " is a nice name! : )");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Thats not a name! : (");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't take `substring(0,1)` of an empty string. Why not check if it's empty *before* you try and do that?

Comment: Please also post the _error_ (full error-message) that was shown to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is probably what you want. Furthermore, I've also highlighted a few best practices.

```
class Main {

    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Point 0 - Use access modifiers!

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("What is your first name?");
        String name = ""; // Point 1 - Initialize your variables to avoid NullPointerException

        // Point 2 - Always check if there is something to read from scanner
        if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            name = scanner.nextLine();
        }

        // Point 3 - You can methods in place instead of stack variables
        if (!name.isEmpty()) {
            if(name.contains(" ")) {
                System.out.println("You put space in your name. : (");
            } else {
                // Point 4 - You can do away with extra variables
                System.out.println(capitalize(name) + " is a nice name! : )");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("That's not a name! : (");
        }

        scanner.close(); // Point 5 - Clean up your resources
    }

    // Point 6 - Concise methods makes code more readable
    private static String capitalize(String str) {
        return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
    }
}
```

You can look up more about [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()).

Comment: string b just capitalizes the first letter of the users name if they did not do so, sorry for not giving much context for that.

Comment: *"Always check"*? Absolutely not, and definitely not like that! --- For simple programs where it's ok for the code to throw exception and terminate when `System.in` is not connected to an input source, not checking is certainly valid coding practice. --- And if you do check, you should definitely handle the case better than printing "That's not a name! : (" and terminating the program when the user hasn't even had a chance to provide input, or pressed Ctrl-Z. --- And don't try to call `close()` outside of a method, because that will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

```
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    System.out.println("What is your first name?");

    String str = scan.nextLine().trim();

    if (str.isEmpty())
        System.err.println("You entered an empty name");
    else if (str.contains(" "))
        System.err.println("You put space in your name.");
    else {
        String name = Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) + str.substring(1);
        System.out.println('\'' + name + "' is a nice name!");
    }
}
```